# Php Function to get html tags from database

Tags: php, mysql, function

I Have a old database to maintain .... they have stored html tags in there database and was using old mysql with php to get outupt ... Now  i am trying to use it through function and PDO to get output .... not getting output right .... its just giving html tags display insted of formatting the paragraph ... how can i fix it , here is my code --> Function

```
function movie_page($name,$date){
    global $host, $dbname, $user, $pass;
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM bh_movies WHERE name = ? and re_date = ?");
    $STH->bindValue(1, "$name", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $STH->bindValue(2, "$date", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $STH->execute();
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $STH;
    }
```

and output is

```
$STH = movie_page($id,$date);
     while (($row = $STH->fetch()) !== false) {
    if ($row['actors'] !=''){
    echo '<tr>
            <td><h1><a href="movie_page.php?id='.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a></h1></td>
            <td>'.date('d-M-Y',$row['re_date']).'</td>
            <td><a href="movie_page.php?id='.$row['name'].'">
            <img src="'.$row['small_poster'].'" title="'.$row['name'].'" alt="'.$row['name'].'" height="97" width="182"/>
            </a>
            </td>
            <td><a href="movie_page.php?id='.$row['a'].'">
            <td>'.$row['actors'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['small_desc'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['big_desc'].'</td>
          </tr>';

     }
```

i am getting Html tags in output ... instead of format paragraph something like this

```
<font color="green"><B><u>Characters</u></B></font><br><br> <B>Sonu Dilli (KKC)</B> Emraan Hashmi<BR><BR> Sonu Dilli is a streetsmart
```

please help

* INPUT Source ***

```
function insert_data(){
    global $host, $dbname, $user, $pass;
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO bh_movies 
    (name, bh_link, re_date,  small_poster, big_poster, small_desc, big_desc, actors) 
    value (:name, :bh_link, :re_date, :small_poster, :big_poster, :small_desc, :big_desc, :actors)");
    return $STH;
}
```

Comment: What format is the HTML in when it enters the database? Can you show the code that is used to enter the stuff?

Comment: @Pekka Same shown in example result ...

Comment: what do you see in the browser's "source code" view?

Comment: @Pekka its braking it down .... &lt;font color=&quot;green&quot;&gt;&lt;B&gt;&lt;u&gt;Characters&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/B&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;    &lt;B&gt;Sonu Dilli

Comment: @Pekka Its not coming in html format

Comment: @Pekka I have added input source also please have a look

Comment: Your data is being converted into HTML entities at some point. Either find the point where it is being converted (probably using `htmlspecialchars()`) or decode the data when it comes from the database (using `htmlspecialchars_decode()`)

Comment: @Pekka Thanks man ... its was encoding while entring data now i am using  htmlspecialchars_decode() and every thing looks good ... how can accept ur this ans ...?and close this question

Comment: I'll turn the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data is being converted into HTML entities at some point. Either find the point where it is being converted (probably using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars)) or decode the data when it comes from the database (using [`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode)).

Comment: For example, if I formatted text as bold, the out put should show bold letters.

Comment: @CJ the same answer applies - find out where tags are converted into entities, and fix it there; or use the decode function

Answer (score 0):

html_entity_decode() to decode the HTML from database.